# WPF. How to show only part of big canvas?

Tags: wpf, resize, wpf-controls, zooming, viewbox

Lets say I have a canvas defined to be 1000x1000 big. Is it possible to only show a 100x100 part of it in a Viewbox(or a rectangel)?

Any help is apreciated.....

Answer (score 7):

If you work with Brushes, you might want to take a look at [Viewbox and Viewport in WPF](http://nayyeri.net/blog/viewbox-and-viewport-in-windows-presentation-foundation/)

**Edit:** I just realised that Viewbox and Viewport are used for Brushes
This is not really appropiate in your situation. I looked it up, and I think you will like the [Clip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip.aspx) property on UIElement.

Since Canvas is also a UIElement, you can use the Clip property to simulate a viewport on your Canvas..

[Click here for some simple Geometry types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751808.aspx#wcpsdk_graphics_geometry_geometrytypes)

I think you would suffice with a RectangleGeometry

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="50,50,25,25" />
    </Canvas.Clip>
</Canvas>
```

**Edit #2:**

Hehe ok.. if you want your total Canvas displayed, only smaller, perheps you should take a look and [LayoutTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx). Then use a [ScaleTranform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform.aspx) to resize your Canvas ;).

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />
    </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
</Canvas>
```

Tweak the parameters until you receive the desired effect ;)

Comment: Viewport is exactly what I want. Unfortunalely there is no such property for the canvas. How can I get around that limitation?

Comment: Hey Erik.. I changed the answer a bit... I think the Clip property will be more appropiate :)

Comment: Thank you! Clip is nearly what I'm searching for. I can clip to show only a part of the canvas.....BUT I want to resize that clipped region fill it's container. Is that possible?

Comment: I must clearify myself. 
I want the clipped region to fill out the same area as the original canvas does.

Comment: ViewBox (not ViewPort) has nothing to do with brushes, and I think it's exactly what you need. Just put your content inside it and set the appropriate properties