# Use a rectangle shape as a clip in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, expression

Is there a way that I can use a normal Rectangle (shape) as part of a clip for another object in XAML.  It seems like I should be able to, but the solution is eluding me..

```
<Canvas>

        <Rectangle Name="ClipRect" RadiusY="10" RadiusX="10" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0" Width="32.4" Height="164"/>

<!-- This is the part that I cant quite figure out.... -->
<Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" Clip={Binding ElementName=ClipRect, Path="??"/>

</Canvas>
```

I know that I can use a 'RectangleGeometry' type approach, but I am more interested in the solution in terms of the code presented above.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321740/wpf-how-to-show-only-part-of-big-canvas

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [Shape.RenderedGeometry Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.renderedgeometry.aspx).

```
<Rectangle Width="100" Height="100"
           Clip="{Binding ElementName=ClipRect, Path=RenderedGeometry}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

`ClipRect.DefiningGeometry` nd `ClipRect.RenderedGeometry` contain only the `RadiusX` and `RadiusY` values but not also `Rect`.

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve (it's not clear to me from your sample) but you could write an `IValueConverter` which would extract the info you require from the referenced `Rectangle`:

```
public class RectangleToGeometryConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var rect = value as Rectangle;

        if (rect == null || targetType != typeof(Geometry))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(new Size(rect.Width, rect.Height)))
        { 
            RadiusX = rect.RadiusX, 
            RadiusY = rect.RadiusY 
        };
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You would then use this converter in your binding definition:

```
<Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" 
            Clip="{Binding ElementName=ClipRect, Converter={StaticResource RectangleToGeometryConverter}}">
```

Of course you need to add the converter to your resources first:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:RectangleToGeometryConverter x:Key="RectangleToGeometryConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: In my example I am trying to clip one Rectangle with the other.  I'm trying to avoid converters / workarounds.

Comment: @A.R. The only way to avoid converters (workarounds as you call them), is to find a [Rectangle property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle_properties.aspx) which contains the info you need. If [RenderedGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle.renderedgeometry.aspx) and [DefiningGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.defininggeometry.aspx) don't have it, you won't be able to avoid at least some code. I find a converter the least "evil" since it's essentially still markup.